# Asp Net Web Form multi select dropdown

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, webforms

I'm trying to do a mulitselect dropdown in an asp net web form legacy project.

I tried using https://github.com/arbh89/DropDownListChosen which works fine, but when i try to add the select tag to the  it deformats on the page.

What I want is a dropdown like this:

[image]

And what I'm getting is this, using mulitple="true":

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Aristos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just check it, this is the normal behavior for **multi select list control** for the List Chosen

To see the list, you just click on the line and the drop down is open to select one more from your list.

Comment: Yes, seems it is. I'll try another bootrstap plugin.